# How to put value in Controller from another Class?

Tags: salesforce, apex, visualforce

I would like to call PageReference from VF Page in another class (Class A) so that it can generate a PDF and set as attachment. The VF Page is getting the ID from its Controller. I want to put the ID from Class A to VF Page so that it will the one to be used rather than the controller.

VF Page Name: ContactDocument

```
public class DocuGenerate {
    public Contact ccc {get;set;} 

    public CaseClosureDocumentController(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
        ccc = (Contact) controller.getRecord();
        ccc = [SELECT ID, NAME FROM CONTACT WHERE ID =: ccc.id];

        //GENERATE A PDF WITH THE ID RETRIEVED.
    }
}


public class SendEmail {
    public static void SendMessage() {
        List<Contact> con = [SELECT ID FROM CONTACT LIMIT 1];
        for(Contact c : con){
            Pagereference vfpage1 = Page.ContactDocument;
            //HOW WILL I PASS CON.ID TO VF PAGE SO THAT IT WILL BE THE ONE TO PROCESS, NOT THE ONE IN VFPAGE?
        }
    }
}
```

EXPECTED: GENERATE A PDF FILE WHEREIN THE INFO IS ABOUT CONTACT ID I HAVE IN ANOTHER CLASS, INSTEAD THE ONE BEING GENERATED IN VF PAGE.

Comment: Question is not clear. You said "The VF Page is getting the ID from its Controller. I want to put the ID from Class A to VF Page" and in the code comment you say "HOW WILL I PASS CON.ID TO VF PAGE SO THAT IT WILL BE THE ONE TO PROCESS, NOT THE ONE IN VFPAGE?" It is confusing. What you want to do ? Want to access the contact from another class rather than the standard controller of the VF page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can make out you want to be sending the Id of the contact from the controller of the page your on now to the PDF Rendering page... You can do this through the page reference and URL Parameters. Adding a parameter to the page reference means that any controller for that page (standard or extension) can get this id and use the record. Here's how you add a parameter to a page reference...

```java
public class SendEmail {
   public static void SendMessage() {
     List<Contact> con = [SELECT ID FROM CONTACT LIMIT 1];
     for(Contact c : con){
       Pagereference vfpage1 = Page.ContactDocument;
       vfpage1.getParameters().put('id', c.id);
       return vfpage1; //You probably need to return the page reference 
                       //in order to redirect to it
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi KDH. I am so sorry I'm not that good in English. But what I want is that I will use the VF Page, that is rendering details of a contact into PDF based on Contact ID, in another Apex Class (not the controller). If it has no Contact ID, VF Page is having error "List has no rows for SObject". How will I pass the Contact ID I have in my Apex Class into that VF Page so that it will be the one the details will be based to.?

Comment: @Marlo it may be easier if you add all the code you have including the visual force pages so we can see exactly what you're trying to do. But I think if you just add what Noor answered `<apex:page standardcontroller="Contact">` to your visualforce page that is rendering and my code to the apex class with the contact it should stop that error

Comment: Hi KDH, actually yours did work! I add ID to parameters and then voila it worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: Oh great! @Marlo

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. What I have understand is, You want to access the contact from another class rather than the standard controller of the VF page.

You can do this by adding an extension controller which refers **class A** in the visualforce page. Then, In the **DocuGenerate** class, create another constructor which receive a **class** A type parameter.

```
<apex:page standardController="yourStandardController" extensions="A">
---
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Hi Noor. I am so sorry I'm not that good in English. But what I want is that I will use the VF Page, that is rendering details of a contact into PDF based on Contact ID, in another Apex Class (not the controller). If it has no Contact ID, VF Page is having error "List has no rows for SObject". How will I pass the Contact ID I have in my Apex Class into that VF Page so that it will be the one the details will be based to.?